# set dynamic title in gnuplot so it can change by time

Tags: gnuplot

How can I set the title of some plot in gnuplot to be dynamic. For example, assume I want to have (it*dt) as title, where "it" is the iteration number and dt is the time step length. What if these parameters are in a .c file and the instructions for plotting are in a .gpl file?

Thanks

Comment: gnuplot -e "a=5; b=8; set title 'XY'; set xlabel 'X'; set ylabel 'Y'" plot.gp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using "title sprintf("t=%i",it*dt)" after plot command. And of course defining "it" and "dt" first.